# Dust on eye piece DSLR

Tags: dslr, nikon-d5100, dust

My DSLR got some dusts on the viewfinder [eye piece]. I've cleaned the both the mirrors [the focus screen] but it looks like the dusts are on where we put our eye.

Should I clean it [dust may find way to the sensor?] or it's best to ignore as there is no effect on the IQ.[image: Dust in view finder]

Answer (score 3):

This happens and while it has no effect on image-quality, it is quite distracting. It looks like you have quite a few and its a good time to clean it.

They make [special cleaning tools for that](http://www.amazon.ca/Lens-Cleaning-Brush-Camera-Viewfinder/dp/B00AXHPTAG) which is basically the same as a lens pen but smaller. The key is not to wet your camera because it is not weather-sealed. Otherwise you can even just rinse it which I've done several times with a number of DSLRs.